# Can $\ln$ be moved out of a limit, similar to an exponent?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

From the Limit Exponent Property:

$$ \lim_{x\to a}[f(x)^n] = [\lim_{x\to a}f(x)]^n $$

Is it also true that

$$ \lim_{x\to a}\ln(f(x)) = \ln(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)) $$

Comment: $\ln$ is a *continuous* function …

Comment: Thanks, I didnt think to think of this as the more general f(g(x)) case that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Limit of composite functions:**
> If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ and $g$ is continuous at $x = L$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(f(x))= g \left( \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \right)$.

In words, that simply means you can move $\lim\limits_{x \to a}$ in and out of $g$ if $g$ is continuous at $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$.

---

Since $\ln ( \cdot )$ is continuous everywhere on $(0, \infty)$, you can move the $\lim\limits_{x \to a}$ in and out of $\ln( \cdot )$ whenever you feel like, as long as the $\lim\limits_{x \to a } f(x)$ is positive, of course.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like many limit rules are just this rule in disguise

Comment: @bgcode Actually I have never heard of "Limit Exponent Property" before. For positive integer $n$ it also follows from the product rule via induction.

Comment: @Gary Would it not also follow from the limit of composite functions rule?

Comment: @bgcode It would. That is why I said "it *also* follows". Note the word *also*.